# How to use grep to reverse search files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to create a script which will find missing topics from multiple log files. These logfiles are filled top down, so the newest logs are at the bottom of the file. I would like to grep only the last line from this file which includes UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION. This should be done in multiple files with completely different names. Is grep the best solution or is there another solution that suits my needs. I already tried adding tail, but that doesn't seem to work.

`missingTopics=$(grep -Ri -m1 --exclude=*.{1,2,3,4,5} UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION /app/tibco/log/tra/domain/)`

Comment: Have a look maybe at `tac` (`man tac`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a combination of `find`, `tac` and `grep`:

```
find /app/tibco/log/tra/domain -type f ! -name '*.[1-5]' -exec sh -c \
  'tac "$1" | grep -im1 UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION' "sh" '{}' \;
```

`tac` prints files in reverse, the `-exec sh -c SCRIPT "sh" '{}' \;` action of `find` executes the shell `SCRIPT` each time a file matching the previous tests is found. The `SCRIPT` is executed with `"sh"` as parameter `$0` and the path of the found file as parameter `$1`.

If performance is an issue you can probably improve it with:

```bash
find . -type f ! -name '*.[1-5]' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do \
  tac "$f" | grep -im1 UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION; done' "sh" '{}' +
```

which will spawn less shells. If security is also an issue you can also replace `-exec` by `-execdir` (even if with this `SCRIPT` I do not immediately see any exploit).